# Error when using 2 Databases in SpringBoot app using annotations

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using 2 Databases in my SpringBoot app..if I put the repositories in 2 different sub-packages with the repository package then it is working fine , but when I put the repos within the repository package and try to connect via annotations..then its not working. Please find the details below and suggest.

```
Config



@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.SpringBoot2DB",
                       includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(FirstDatabase.class),
                       entityManagerFactoryRef = "spdbEM",
                       transactionManagerRef = "spdbTM")
public class SPDBConfiguration {

    // DataSource
    @Primary
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(value = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource spdbDatasource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .build();
    }

    // EntityManager (datasource)
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean spdbEM(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder, @Qualifier("spdbDatasource") DataSource spdbDatasource) {
        return entityManagerFactoryBuilder
                .dataSource(spdbDatasource)
                .packages("com.example.SpringBoot2DB.entity")
                .build();
    }

    // JpaTransactionManager (entityManager)
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager spdbTM(@Qualifier("spdbEM") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean spdbEM) {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(spdbEM.getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }


}

Repo

@FirstDatabase
public interface FoodRepository extends JpaRepository<Food, Integer>{

}


Entity 

@Entity
@Table(name="FOOD")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Food {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    
    @Column(name = "food_name")
    private String foodName;
    
    @Column(name = "food_type")
    private String foodType;

}
```

Error :: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "food" does not exist